# Check if date is within time range using Joda or standard Java API

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime, date-range

I have first time as string '12:00:00' and another '19:00:00'. How to check time portion of the day is within these time values?

Answer (score 51):

Using Joda Time you could do something like this:

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(2010, 5, 25, 12, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime end = new DateTime(2010, 5, 25, 21, 0, 0, 0);
Interval interval = new Interval(start, end);
DateTime test = new DateTime(2010, 5, 25, 16, 0, 0, 0);
System.out.println(interval.contains(test));
```

Comment: Worth remembering `interval.contains()` excludes the end date. See http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractInterval.html#contains-org.joda.time.ReadableInterval-

Comment: Interval(from, to).containsNow() if you need to check current time in range

Answer (score -1):

Create calendar instances of the start and end times for the same day as your 'test' date. Then you can easily compare the calendar objects to determine if the current date is inside or outside the range.